# Browser reading the CSS but not rendering it?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

So I'm following [a tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=70Pu_28yvdI&t=4025s) on RoR (-v 4.2.5), and around the 1 hr mark, he starts adding the styles. When I tried to reproduce it, it would not render.

When I inspect an element, for example (intro), it shows me these lines from the application.scss : (but it doesn't render it)

```
body {
    font-family: "Proxima Nova";
    font-weight: 100;
}
```

Also, there are more attributes added as `@import` to this element in the application.css.scss that should be inherited, and it also doesn't render them.
 However, the browser actually successfully reads and compiles the whole thing, (The application.scss and the `@import` that it has), but it doesn't render any of that stuff either.

**Where I think the problem is:**
These 2 lines on my application.html? Somehow? But I don't know why or how. I went to the page and copied the current version, (The exact link differs a bit from the one of the tutorial, but I also tried the old one and no luck)

```
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/7.0.0/normalize.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

What rookie mistake am I making??
[Here's my repo](https://github.com/mickeytgl/muse/tree/master/app/assets/stylesheets)

Cheers, Miguel

Comment: is the proxima nova webfont file loaded and loading properly?

Comment: When using `normalize` you should add the link above your own stylesheet since the rules in `normalize.css` will override your own styles.

Comment: Is your website being served over http or https? Check your console to see if the https stylesheets are being received.

Comment: Is your HTML being rendered properly? What if you moved some sample styles into a `<style type="text/css>` in your `<head>` within the markup you know is working?

Answer (score 0):

I checked out that repo where the demo was from and ran it locally. Not sure why the demo put that font `Proxima Nova`, as `normalize` and `font-awesome` both do not carry that `font-family` type. I couldn't find anywhere else in your repo where you may have had that font located.

If you remove the `font-family` from your file you will see that the font defaults to `normalize`'s font `sans-serif`.

As far as somethings I noticed in your **application.html.erb**, on line 36 replace `</wrapper>` with `</div>` as it looks like you originally set the class `wrapper`. Also as mentioned in the comments move your CDN links above the `stylesheet_link_tag` as any matching properties from your own CSS file will be overwritten.

If you are still looking to use the `Proxima Nova` font you can check out this gist: https://gist.github.com/haggen/2624063

Choose one of the `@font-family`'s and paste it above your `body` property in **application.css.scss** and you will have a way of using that font.